# Can I display html from a remote destination in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, html

Can I display html content from a remote destination in an iphone app? For example, is it possible to load an iframe from a remote source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a native app, you can use [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to embed web content.